# Does the definition of the linear span of a subset of a vector space require that the set be countable?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My book gives this definition of linear span of a subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ :

> Now if $S$ is any subset of $V$, we let $L(S)$ be the set of all finite linear combinations of elements of $S$. Thus
>   $$L(S) = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^k{\alpha_i v_i \mid k \in \mathbb{N}, v_i \in S, \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}}\right\}.$$

But when we write $k \in \mathbb{N}$, aren't we implying that $S$ is at most countable?
That is, $S=\{v_i:i=1(1)k,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. But $S$ may very well be an uncountable subset.

Comment: What has $k$ got to do with S$???

Comment: Is the number of elements you take to form the linear combination of elements of $S$

Comment: Note that $v_1,v_2,\ldots$ are not fixed. Every element of the set $S$ appears in some finite subset or $S$, and the linear span is defined to be the set of all linear combinations of *all* finite subsets of $S$.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to hear. It only makes sense to me if the $v_i$s were not fixed. The notation makes that kind of an impression to me though. Thanks for saying that.

Comment: Variables that are on the right side of the vertical bar of the set builder notation are assumed to range over every possible element of the set they are in. Notice that you didn't think that $k$ was fixed, or the $\alpha_i$ either.

Comment: I realized this after a while. Thank you for confirming it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Indeed, $S$ may be an uncountable subset.

However, the notation in any case means that you consider **finite** sums (not countable sums).

Regardless the cardinality of $S$, the linear span is the set of all elements that you can write as a sum  of *finitely* many terms of the form $\lambda s$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s \in S$.

You can use each element of $S$ but you can, for any given sum, only combine it with finitely many other elements of $S$.

For example, if you consider the vector space of infinite real sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and for  $j \in \mathbb{N}$ you set $e_j$ the sequence that has $j$-th term $1$ and is $0$ otherwise. (So something that resembles the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Then the span of $\{e_j \colon j \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is **not the full space.** 
Instead the span is the subspaces of sequences that have only a finite number of non-zero terms.

(There is a related notion that does allow countable sums, see [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) but this is something other than what you are considering.)

---

Let me add that using your notation $v_1$ is *not one fixed element* of $S$ it is just some kind of dummy-variable. The $v_1$ in one sum, will not be the same as a $v_1$ in another sum (it could be, say, $v_2$ or not appear at all).

Comment: Yes the last part is what I was confused about. Looking at the set I got the impression that the $v_i$s were all fixed elements of $S$.

Comment: I am glad this is settled. I only realized this was the issue when I saw your comment on Hector's answer. But in retrospect it makes sense and I now agree that the notation is possibly a bit imprecise (though very common).

Answer (score 7):

The definition says that $S$ is **any subset** of $V$. The important thing here is to understand that the span of $S$ is the set of all ***finite linear combinations*** of elements in $S$.

The condition $k\in\mathbb{N}$ means that **the sum (the linear combination)** is **finite.**

The parameter $k$ is the number of vector (in $S$) you take to form the linear combination of elements of S.

To have an element of $L(S)$ you have to:

1) Choose $k\in\mathbb{N}$

2) Choose any $k$ vectors in $S$

3) Form the linear combination of this vectors and this will be your element in $L(S)$. This is, we variate the scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

To have all elements in $L(S)$ you can vary the parameter $k$ and  then you vary the choice of $k$ vectors in $S$ and of course, you vary the scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I hear you. But suppose that $S$ is not countable. Then when we take the vectors $v_1, v_2,..., v_k$ from $S$, and we let $k$ vary within the set of all natural numbers, aren't we missing out on some of the vectors from $S$?

Comment: To have an element of $L(S)$ you have to take any finite subset of $S$ to form the linear combination with it's elements.

Answer (score 4):

No, restricting $k\in\mathbb{N}$ does not require $S$ to be countable.

Consider the example of $S$ a line through the origin, i.e. the set of $\alpha v$ for some fixed $v$ as $\alpha$ ranges through $\mathbb{R}$. Then $S$ is uncountable, but $L(S)$ is still perfectly well-defined, and indeed $L(S)=S$.

Comment: The question did not ask if $L(S)$ is countable, but rather if $S$ most be countable.

Comment: I didn't say that $L(S)$ is countable. I was referring to the set $S$.

Comment: Whoops, thanks; yes, I misread $L(S)$ for $S$ in your question, because that question is more reasonable. It doesn't matter whether $S$ is uncountable.